# How to link to another workbook and get data?

Tags: excel, vba

I use this code to get data from any workbook.

```
Range("A1:C100") = "=IFERROR('[File.xlsb]Sheet1'!RC,0)"
```

The code was working.

I applied some other macros to get data from closed workbooks.

Now I get an error *Method_Default of object 'Range' failed* or formula pasted, but links not updating.

I want to select workbook and sheet (any) and get data to active workbook, and when I cancel (X) selection window it must exit sub.

```vb
Option Exlicit
Sub GETPRICE()
    With Sheets("BINO")
        .Range("A1:C100000") =" =IFERROR(IF('[FILE.xlsb]SHEET'!RC=0,"""",'[FILE.xlsb]SHEET'!RC),0)"
        .Range("D1:D100000") = "=TRIM(LEFT(RC[-3],250)&LEFT(RC[-2],2))"
        .Range("E1:E100000") = "=IFERROR(ROUND(RC[-2],4),"""")"
        .Range("A1:E100000").Value2 = Sheets("BINO").Range("A1:E100000").Value2
        
        With Sheets("BINO").Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E1:E100000"), Order:=xlDescending
            .SetRange Range("D5:E5000")
            .Header = xlNo
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

If I mention as `Range("A1:C100").FormulaR1C1` then I get error

> Method 'FormulaR1C1' of object 'Range' failed

Comment: Should be `Range("A1:C100").FormulaR1C1` probably but that doesn't explain the error. What is the rest of the code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of posting code in comments, thanks.